# Promise is never fulfilling

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, selenium-webdriver

The following code never hits the console log points "post4" or "post3". It does return the promise but if I try to chain from that promise the chain is never followed.

```
loginPage.prototype.doLogin = function(isGood){
    var d = webdriver.promise.defer();
    this.driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css('input.loginbutton')).click(function() {
        if(isGood){
            //return new statementPage;
            console.log("post3")
            d.fulfill(new statement.statementPage(this.driver));
        } else {
            console.log("post4")
            d.fulfill(this);
        }
    });
    console.log("post5")
    return d.promise;
}
```

If I call `login.doLogin(true).then(function(){console.log("foo")})` it'll never log post3, post4 or foo.

I've got other promises working successfully elsewhere in my code so I don't understand why this isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `click` function of webdriverjs does not take any parameters/callbacks, therefore your function was never being run. The `click` code follows (from the [API](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/source/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js.src.html#l1713)):

```
webdriver.WebElement.prototype.click = function() {
  return this.schedule_(
      new webdriver.Command(webdriver.CommandName.CLICK_ELEMENT),
      'WebElement.click()');
};
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/who_stow/z38JV/3/) showing that a js function that takes in no parameters does not actually use the parameter unless specified with the `arguments` variable.

Using the then `element.click().then(function(){d.fulfill()});` allows the click promise to be fulfilled and then run your code. Read up on the promises from the [Webdriverjs Page](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#Promises)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a callback such as

```
element.click(function(){d.fulfill(););
```

You should use the promise from the click, so:

```
element.click().then(function(){d.fulfill()});
```

Comment: Having answered my own question I don't actually fully understand why the second one works but the first doesn't. I'm assuming it's to do with the way closures work and scope. If someone can provide a better answer with the reason why this is I'll accept it.